# Error ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE when sending message from Viber bot to botbuilder-viber

Tags: node.js, express, botframework, bots, viber

**Problem in npm-module**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-viber

**Platform**

Operating System: Ubuntu

Node Version: 9.3.0

NPM Version: 5.5.1.

**Code**

```
var viber = require('botbuilder-viber');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var viberOptions = {
  Token: '***',
  Name: '***',
  AvatarUrl: '***'
}
var viberChannel = new viber.ViberEnabledConnector(viberOptions);

var expressApp = express();

expressApp.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function() {
    console.log("Express server is running.");
});

expressApp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

expressApp.use(bodyParser.json());

bot.connector(viber.ViberChannelId, viberChannel);

expressApp.use('/viber/webhook', viberChannel.listen());
```

**Expected Behavior**

No error

**Actual Behavior**

Error (repeats twice everytime) when I sending message from my viber bot.

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be one of type string, TypedArray, or DataView
at Hmac.update (internal/crypto/hash.js:53:11)
at MessageValidator._calculateHmacFromMessage (/app/node_modules/viber-bot/lib/message/message-validator.js:17:54)
at MessageValidator.validateMessage (/app/node_modules/viber-bot/lib/message/message-validator.js:11:30)
at _app.use (/app/node_modules/viber-bot/lib/middleware.js:61:32)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at textParser (/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/text.js:60:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (/app/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at query (/app/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/query.js:45:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be one of type string, TypedArray, or DataView
at Hmac.update (internal/crypto/hash.js:53:11)
at MessageValidator._calculateHmacFromMessage (/app/node_modules/viber-bot/lib/message/message-validator.js:17:54)
at MessageValidator.validateMessage (/app/node_modules/viber-bot/lib/message/message-validator.js:11:30)
at _app.use (/app/node_modules/viber-bot/lib/middleware.js:61:32)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at textParser (/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/text.js:60:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (/app/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at query (/app/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/query.js:45:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)

Comment: Have you tried this without using express?

Comment: Yes, I tried with Restify, instead of error nothing happens when I sending message. Back to Express: I completly removed bodyParser.json (same express.json) and this viber-connector starts to work, but now I can't deal with endpoints of my project, because of removing json parsing.

Comment: @EricDahlvang  I found descision in bodyparser documentation :) Adding bodyparser to specific router: `var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();  app.post('/api/users', jsonParser, function (req, res) {})`

Comment: I think you will need to ask the authors of https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-viber for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added bodyparser only to specific routes, after this connector starts to work.