# Viber setWebhook failed with error - The "data" argument must be one of type string, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type object

Tags: node.js, bots, webhooks, viber, viber-api

Trying to setup a viber webhook. I already have an express server setup. So I just add the bot as middleware. Everything is find and the server is up and running.

Once called `bot.setWebhook(process.env.VB_WEBHOOK_URL)`, it throws error saying --> `The "data" argument must be one of type string, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type object`

It works fine when trying with `ngrok` in local server configuration. The only issue when setting up the webhook in live server configuration. Please check the code below

```
        const path = require("path");
        const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, "../public");
        const express = require("express");
        const http = require("http");
        const env = require("dotenv");
        const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
        env.config({
            path: path.resolve(__dirname + "/.env")
        });
        const app = express();
        const server = http.createServer(app);
        
        const adminActionRoute = require('./routes/admin');

        app.use(express.static(publicPath));
        app.use(bodyParser.json({ verify: verifyRequestSignature }));
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '200mb', extended: true                         }));
        app.use('/api/admin', adminActionRoute);
        
        const viberBot = require('../viber_chat/utils/bot')
        app.use('/viber/webhook', viberBot.middleware())
        
        server.listen(5000, () => {
            viberBot.setWebhook(process.env.VB_WEBHOOK_URL);
            console.log("server starts at port 5000");
        });


        module.exports = server; //for testing
```

'/viber_chat/utils/bot' file

```
        require('dotenv').config();
        const ViberBot = require('viber-bot').Bot;
        const BotEvents = require('viber-bot').Events;
        const logger = require('../utils/logger');

        const bot = new ViberBot(logger, {
            authToken: process.env.VB_API_KEY, 
            name: "Bot Name",
            avatar: "" 
        });

        bot.onSubscribe(response => {
           
        });

        bot.on(BotEvents.CONVERSATION_STARTED, (response) => {
        
        })


        module.exports = bot;
```

```sh
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be one of type string, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type object
    at Hmac.update (internal/crypto/hash.js:58:11)
    at MessageValidator._calculateHmacFromMessage (/home/thettun/project_folder/funfun_viber/node_modules/viber-bot/lib/message/message-validator.js:19:54)
    at MessageValidator.validateMessage (/home/thettun/project_folder/funfun_viber/node_modules/viber-bot/lib/message/message-validator.js:11:30)
    at _app.use (/home/thettun/project_folder/funfun_viber/node_modules/viber-bot/lib/middleware.js:61:32)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/thettun/project_folder/funfun_viber/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/thettun/project_folder/funfun_viber/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/thettun/project_folder/funfun_viber/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/thettun/project_folder/funfun_viber/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/thettun/project_folder/funfun_viber/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at textParser (/home/thettun/project_folder/funfun_viber/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/text.js:60:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/thettun/project_folder/funfun_viber/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/thettun/project_folder/funfun_viber/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/thettun/project_folder/funfun_viber/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/thettun/project_folder/funfun_viber/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/thettun/project_folder/funfun_viber/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/home/thettun/project_folder/funfun_viber/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
```

Comment: is `process.env.VB_API_KEY` there? can you reconfirm? By console logging

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Yes. process.env.VB_API_KEY prints the key. console.log() shows the key.

Answer (score 1):

this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50447040/error-err-invalid-arg-type-when-sending-message-from-viber-bot-to-botbuilder-vib) solved it for me

i.e. don't use bodyParser when calling setWebhook, only on specific routes:

```
// app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: You should elaborate more on  your answer. A brief response like this is more appropriate for a comment than an answer